# Pass pointer of an array of multi-dimensional arrays to a function, specifying bounds

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameters, declaration

Let's say I have multiple (a variable number) of 2D arrays (which may even be variable-length):

```
int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int b[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};
...
```

which I now want to pass to a function. I do *not* want to copy the 2D arrays into 3D array. However, I want to specify the bounds so that the function knows the dimensions of the 2D arrays so that I can index them conveniently with `[i][j]`

How can I format the functions' signature so that it accepts a pointer to an array (of unknown length) which contains 2D arrays of which it *does* now the dimensions?

E.g. something like

```
void myfunc(int[][3] *test, int len)
```

though of course this is syntactically invalid. Is specifying the bounds of arrays *inside* an array (passed by pointer) impossible in C? Will I be forced to move `a` and `b` into pointers, or forced to copy them into a 3D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compiler supports a variable length arrays you can write

```
void myfunc( int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols] );
```

Take into account that the third parameter is implicitly converted to the type `int ( * )[cols]`, that is within a function you are dealing with a pointer to one dimensional array. Nevertheless you can use expressions like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) a[i][j] = value;
}
```

Otherwise if the compiler does not support variable length arrays and the second dimension of all arrays is the same then the function can be declared like

void myfunc( int ( *a )[2], int rows );

Take into account that this declaration

```
int[][3] *test
```

in any case is incorrect.

If you want to pass several two-dimensional arrays then you can within main declare a one dimensional array like

```
int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int b[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};
//...

int ( *p[] )[2] = { a, b, /*...*/ };
```

and then pass it to a function.

In this case the function will look like

```
void myfunc( int ( **p )[2], size_t n );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc( int ( **p )[2], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
        {
            for ( size_t k = 0; k < 2; k++ ) printf( "%d ", p[i][j][k] );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    int b[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};

    int ( *p[] )[2] = { a, b };

    myfunc( p, sizeof( p ) / sizeof( *p ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 
3 4 

5 6 
7 8
```

If the first dimension of the arrays is not fixed and varies then you could pass also to the function an array of first dimensions of the arrays

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. Let's take your answer, but modify it so that I pass *multiple* `a`. Maybe each `a` lives in an array, or maybe it's in the heap. How can you update your `myfunc` signature so that the compiler knows the dimensions of each `a`?

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks promising! However, I'm a little paranoid it works because there are an equal number of 2D arrays as dimensions. I.e. I'm suspecting `(**p)[2]` notatonally indicates that the *outer* array has length 2 (`a` and `b`) rather than indicating that the inner-most dimension is `2`. Ergo I'm baffled by how it work

Comment: @AntiEarth I[2]  measn the second (right-most) dimension of the arrays a and b that are declared like for example int a[2][2]

Comment: Ahh I see, because of the *brackets* around `*p[]`! So `int **p[2]` reads as 'outer most has dim 2', but `int (**p)[2]` reads as 'inner most has dim2'? This is really helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two *things* you need to pass to a function, you either

1. pass two separate arguments; or
2. create some kind of data structure that contains (pointers to) said *things*, and pass (a pointer to) that.

It doesn't matter if your *things* are arrays or anything else.

The same thing holds when you have a variable number of *things*. You can pass a variable number of arguments to a function, but that's a separate topic, so let's concentrate in option 2. In this case your data structure should be an array of pointers to *things*.

OK so how do you create one when your *thing* has a complex type, like an array (of arrays of pointers to functions that return a pointer to an array, or whatever)? The answer is simple: use a typedef.

```
typedef int MyThing[2][2]; // could be anything
MyThing one = {{1,2},{3,4}};
MyThing two = ...; // etc

MyThing* manyPointersToThings[] = {&one, &two};

void myFunc(int nThings, MyThing things[nThings]) {

   // in here, each things[i] is a *pointer* to MyThing
   (*things[0])[1][2] = 42;
    // whatever
}
```

This works for any kind of *thing*. If your *thing* is in fact an array, there is another option: your data structure could store pointers to first elements of your arrays, rather than pointers to arrays themselves.

```
typedef int MyThing[2]; // this type names an *element* of your array
MyThing one[2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
MyThing two[2] = ...; // etc

MyThing* manyPointersToThings[] = {one, two}; // note no & here

void myFunc(int nThings, MyThing things[nThings]) {

   // in here, each things[i] is a pointer to the first element of an array
   things[0][1][2] = 42;
    // whatever
}
```

With this option, you gain some flexibility, as your arrays need not all be of the same size. You also lose that ugly dereference in parentheses.

For completeness, here are prototypes of the same functions sans typedef:

```
void myFunc(int nThings, int (*things[nThings])[2][2]) // version 1
void myFunc(int nThings, int (*things[nThings])[2]) // version 2
```

These are a bit more flexible than typedef versions, because now you can use a variable (another parameter) instead of the hardcoded number 2.

If you have trouble writing down things like the above, try [this](https://cdecl.org/).